# Why am I getting an uninitialized constant error when the model file exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting the following error in pry after creating the model. I think I have all the pieces in place so cant be sure why. I haven't created the controller yet but I think I should still be able to access my model in pry before setting up the model.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Deal
```

app/models/deal.rb

```
class Deal < ApplicationRecord
end
```

db/schema.rb

```
  create_table "deals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "origin_city"
    t.string "destination_city"
    t.date "fly_out"
    t.date "check_in"
    t.date "check_out"
    t.date "trip_end"
    t.float "flight_price"
    t.float "hotel_price"
    t.date "date"
    t.integer "number_nights"
    t.string "hotel_link"
    t.string "search_results_link"
    t.string "flight_link"
    t.string "region"
    t.string "country"
  end
```

Comment: If you open the Rails console and type Deal what is the result? (Is that what you mean by "in Pry"?

Comment: @LesNightingill yep, I do that. It says NameError: uninitialized constant Deal. Seems like it can't find the model but I'm not sure why. The naming seems right to me.

Comment: what version of Rails are you running?

Comment: In Rails 7, the mapping from constants to files follows the Zeitwerk paradigm. You are doing it correctly, according to the code that you have shared. I surmise that there is something that you have not shown us that is causing the problem. If you are running Rails 7, then from the command line run `bin/rails zeitwerk:check` to see if there are any errors. Your code looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct. The problem was in opening pry and not the rails console to check the model connection.

```
bundle exec rails c
```

Using the above and going into pry via the console vs. just opening it works.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know you worked it out.  Also, take a look at [the `pry-rails` gem](https://github.com/pry/pry-rails) to use pry automatically as your rails console.